# Issue with Standalone in Processing

Tags: import, export, processing, windows-7-x64

I have a sketch running in `Processing 2.1.2`, and it runs fine from the sketch window.  When I try to export it to a standalone windows application,  Processing creates the application.windows folder, which contains the 'lib' and 'source' subdirectories. But when I double-click the application,  it just showing me a blank window.

Can anybody guide me on how do I resolve this issue?
Coding of program is given below:

```
import toxi.geom.*;
import toxi.geom.mesh.*;
import toxi.processing.*;
import processing.serial.*;
TriangleMesh mesh;
ToxiclibsSupport gfx;
PImage img;
String input;
Serial port;
int x,y,z;
void setup() {
  size(448, 299,P3D);
  println(Serial.list());
  port = new Serial(this,Serial.list()[0], 9600);
  port.bufferUntil('\n');
  mesh=(TriangleMesh)new STLReader().loadBinary(sketchPath("check.stl"),STLReader.TRIANGLEMESH);
  gfx=new ToxiclibsSupport(this);
  img=loadImage("imagei.jpg");
}
void draw() {
  background(img);
  translate(width/2,height/2,0);
  rotateX(radians(x));     // Pitch
  rotateY(radians(y));    // Roll
  rotateZ(radians(z));   // Yaw
  directionalLight(192, 168, 128,0, -1000, -0.5);
  directionalLight(255, 64, 0, 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.1f);
  noStroke();
  scale(2);  
  gfx.mesh(mesh,false);
}
void serialEvent(Serial port)
{
 input = port.readString();
 if(input != null) {
   String[] values = split(input, " ");
   println(values[0]);
   println(values[1]);
   println(values[2]);
   x= int(values[0]);y= int(values[1]);z= int(values[2]);
 } 
}
```

Comment: How did you add mysummervacation.jpg to the sketch? Make sure you use the "Add file..." menu. Try deleting that file and re-adding it through that menu.

Comment: @KevinWorkman  Thank for your help ....image is working fine....Wht ab8 sketchPath, how should I add it..

Comment: It looks like you've changed the code you posted. There's a known bug with exporting sketches that use the serial library. Try using the latest version of Processing 3 instead. If that doesn't work, try running the application via the command prompt so you can see any errors  you're getting.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I run above code after minor editing on `Processing 2.1.2` and export it as application, working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit this line of program:

mesh=(TriangleMesh)new STLReader().loadBinary(sketchPath("check.stl"),STLReader.TRIANGLEMESH);

by:

> mesh=(TriangleMesh)new STLReader().loadBinary(sketchPath("data/check.stl"),STLReader.TRIANGLEMESH);

and rest of the program is fine, just check it and let me know if you get any error.